# Devise, ActionController::UnknownFormat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using devise for authentication, and my application send email with confirmation, but when I click 'confirm my account' I have this error:

> ActionController::UnknownFormat

Where is my problem?

my **application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def authenticate_admin_user!
    authenticate_user!
    redirect_to root_path unless current_user.admin?
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :first_name << :last_name
  end
end
```

my **confirmation_instructions.html**

```
<p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', user_confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %></p>
```

Comment: show the code from your confirmations controller

Comment: Sorry, I'm junior in RoR, i don't see confirmations_controller.rb in app/controllers. This controller invisible?

Comment: this controller is implemented by devise, but could be overridden by the developer, that's why I asked. The problem you are facing is most likely related to the `respond_to` block in it. But if you didn't override any action of it I don't know, which version of devise do you use?

Comment: Can you post the request log so we can see what type of request is being sent to which controller

Comment: Started GET "/users/confirmation.9?confirmation_token=s6zbCegXqcY4hiyDvpNV" for
Processing by Devise::ConfirmationsController#show as 
  Parameters: {"confirmation_token"=>"s6zbCegXqcY4hiyDvpNV"}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."confirmation_token" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["confirmation_token", "s6zbCegXqcY4hiyDvpNV"]]
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 108ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)

Answer (score 3):

Just add this `respond_to :html, :json` line in your `application controller`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :html, :json
  ...
```

Comment: Can u pls try adding ':format => :html' in your link_to tag?